# How to write a method in c# to test if two entity type objects are equal or not in a test class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing a test method to check if two entity objects are equal or not. I also need to compare each item of those two entity objects.

```
public class DatabaseServiceTestBase<TEntity, TContext, TService>
    where TEntity : IBaseModel<Guid>
    where TContext : DatabaseContext
    where TService : IDatabaseService<TEntity, Guid>
{
    public abstract class ContextBase
    {
        public TService Service { get; set; }

        public TContext Context { get; }

        public ContextBase(string databaseName)
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: databaseName)
                .Options;

            Context = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), new object[] { options });
        }


        // how to implement AssertObjectsEqual method?
        public virtual void AssertObjectsEqual(TEntity expected, TEntity actual)
        {

        }                   

    }
}
```

How to implement an `AssertObjectsEqual` method? I am new to a generic types.

Comment: Equal as in the same *instance*, or equal as in share the same *data*?

Comment: Equal as in the same instance

Comment: `expected == actual` or `object.ReferenceEquals(expected, actual)` ?

Comment: @TheGeneral  Do you think following code checks the items within entity as well?Please help.                                                                                              
 public virtual void AssertObjectsEqual(TEntity expected, TEntity actual)
 {
      object.ReferenceEquals(expected, actual)  
  }

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
expected == actual
```

or

```
object.ReferenceEquals(expected, actual)
```

> Do you think following code checks the items within entity as well?

The same *instances* shares the same *references* to the same *items*. It's like asking if 2 buckets are the same. If the buckets are the same then the *items* in the *bucket* must be the same. You can't have the same bucket with different items no matter how *nested* it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @TheGeneral

Answer (score 0):

If you need structural comparison then you can use existing frameworks.

- [DeepEqual](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeepEqual/)
- [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) ShouldBeEquivalentTo

Find more options in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530982/c-sharp-asserting-two-objects-are-equal-in-unit-tests).