# Try catch with list of assertion information

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a list that contain information that I want to assert. I want to assert in a table on a webpage

My Code looks:

```
for (var X = 0; X < test.Count; X++)
{
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            if (GetElement(i).Text == test[X].Type.ToString())
            {
                switch (test[X].Type)
                {
                    case Enum.Type.X:
                        [Asserts]
                         break;
                    case Enum.Type.Y:
                        [Asserts]
                        break;
                    case Enum.Type.Z:                                                                                
                    [Asserts]
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException($"text");
    }
}
```

What I want:

- I want that for each line in the list it goes to do if statement. If the statement is correct Assert Are Done.
- When Asserts are correct is should go back and start with the second record in the list (named test).
- If the if statement is never true  a catch (NoSuchElementException) should appear.

The list looks has 4 fields, most of the time it has 3 records, sometimes 4 records depending on the situation.

I want each record in the list be checked.

Currently it only checks the first record in the list and then it stops. While I want each record in the list to be checked.

If more information is needed, let me know.

Comment: wow, the level of nesting makes it hard to read. Can you track the problem using a debugger?

Comment: I tried but was not able to fix it with debugger thats why I asked it here.

Comment: You have a `break` at the end of the `try` which will cause the  outter loop to never get past `X` = 0

Comment: The `break` would have been easily found with the debugger...

Comment: I want it to stop when assertion fails.

Comment: @xxx2017 If X=0 and the if is false for all the values of i then you hit that break and it never tries any values of X larger than 0.  Basically as it is now you could remove the outter loop and just replace X with 0 and get the same results.

Comment: Have you considered comparing the two lists? If you use NUnit, there are methods that do this for you, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861619/nunit-comparing-two-lists. The code would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `break` for an inner loop to `break` the outer loop you need to do that using some type of flag.  You can use that flag in the condition of both loops and instead of the `break` from the inner loop you just set the flag accordingly.  Also you need to remove the `break` from the end of the `try` as that stops the outer loop from doing more than one iteration.  If you only want it to `break` on the [Asserts] then you'd move the code that sets the flag to each `case` accordingly.

```
bool keepGoing = true;
for (var X = 0; X < test.Count && keepGoing; X++)
{
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 4 && keepGoing; i++)
        {
            if (GetElement(i).Text == test[X].Type.ToString())
            {
                switch (test[X].Type)
                {
                    case Enum.Type.X:
                        [Asserts]
                         break;
                    case Enum.Type.Y:
                        [Asserts]
                        break;
                    case Enum.Type.Z:                                                                                
                        [Asserts]
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                keepGoing = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException($"text");
    }
}
```

Comment: The first in the list goes fine (0) when it finishes the asserts correctly . It then goes back to for (var X = 0; X < test.Count && keepGoing; X++)

Now X=1. When I continue it is not going into:

                try
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= 4 && keepGoing; i++)

But skips that part and goes out of the method as if it finished everything.

Comment: Was `GetElement(i).Text == test[X].Type.ToString()` true for `X=0` and `0<=i<=4`?  If so then `keepGoing` would be set to `false` and both loops with break.  Also make sure `test.Count` is greater than 1.

Comment: I removed  keepgoing from the first for and lowered bool keepGoing = true; a bit. Then it worked the way I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @xxx2017 Then that's just the same as removing the second `break` from your original code.  I thought you wanted to stop the outter loop as well when the `if` in the inner loop was true.  If not, then I'd just go back to one `break` in the inner loop and get rid of `keepGoing`.