# Compare two dates using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, nunit

In my unit tests, using NUnit, I'm trying to compare the equality of two objects using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352071/1179061)

```
public static void AreEqualByJson(object expected, object actual)
{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var expectedJson = serializer.Serialize(expected);
    var actualJson = serializer.Serialize(actual);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedJson, actualJson);
}
```

It works fine but for a property which is DateTime where it raises this error

```
String lengths are both 498. Strings differ at index 65.
Expected: "...onDateTime":"\\/Date(1410857388258)\\/","TransactionID":"Tra..."
But was:  "...onDateTime":"\\/Date(1410857388000)\\/","TransactionID":"Tra..."
---------------------------------------------^
```

The code that I'm using for that is this

```
[Test]
public void FromResponseToDecisionResponse_MapsAllProperties()
{
    //Arrange

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var sourceResponse = CreateSourceResponse(now);
    var targetDecisionResponse = CreateTargetDecisionResponse(now);

    //Act
    var mappedResponse = _mapper.FromResponseToDecisionResponse(sourceResponse);

    //Assert 
    AreEqualByJson(targetDecisionResponse, mappedResponse);
}
```

Being

```
private static Response CreateSourceResponse(DateTime now)
{
    var sourceResponse = new Response
    {
        //More properties
        TransactionDateTime = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sss")
    };
    return sourceResponse;
}

private static DecisionResponse CreateTargetDecisionResponse(DateTime now)
{
    var targetDecisionResponse = new DecisionResponse
    {
        //Other properties
        TransactionDateTime =  now,
        //More properties
    };
    return targetDecisionResponse;
}
```

Just before going into AreEqualByJson the dates are the same, but when they are serialized I got this offset that makes my test fail.

Is there something wrong or I should treat all dates as particular cases in AreEqualByJson (still maintaining it as a reusable method)?

Thanks,

UPDATE

As per Marc Gravell comment I ended up doing this in CreateTargetDecisionResponse

TransactionDateTime = DateTime.Parse(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sss"))

Comment: They are different by 258ms; since you seem to be using `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sss`, I'm not sure that this sub-second difference should be unexpected...

Comment: Thanks, @MarcGravell. You're completely right. I ended up doing some tricky thing (see update) but as it's just for a private method for this particular test I'm happy with it.

Comment: It would be cleaner to compare strong-typed with a generic method. If you don't want to introduce dependencies on certain classes in the tests, you can serialize the objects (I'd suggest to use Json.Net for that as it's ~3 times as fast) and then deserialize them (with JavaScriptSerializer) into Dictionary<string, dynamic>.

Answer (score 0):

Object 1, `TransactionDateTime = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sss")` (and assuming `FromResponseToDecisionResponse` is converting the string back to DateTime)

Object 2, `TransactionDateTime =  now,`
It can only be a coincidence if the two turn out to be same.. i.e. when `now` does not have any fractional seconds what so ever...

That's the most obvious incorrect part of the test.