# Apply GetProperties to interface only

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Please see the code below:

```
public static class AssertEx
{
    public static void PropertyValuesAreEquals(object actual, object expected)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = expected.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object expectedValue = property.GetValue(expected, null);
            object actualValue = property.GetValue(actual, null);

            if (actualValue is IList)
                AssertListsAreEquals(property, (IList)actualValue, (IList)expectedValue);
            else if (!Equals(expectedValue, actualValue))
                Assert.Fail("Property {0}.{1} does not match. Expected: {2} but was: {3}", property.DeclaringType.Name, property.Name, expectedValue, actualValue);
        }
    }

    private static void AssertListsAreEquals(PropertyInfo property, IList actualList, IList expectedList)
    {
        if (actualList.Count != expectedList.Count)
            Assert.Fail("Property {0}.{1} does not match. Expected IList containing {2} elements but was IList containing {3} elements", property.PropertyType.Name, property.Name, expectedList.Count, actualList.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < actualList.Count; i++)
            if (!Equals(actualList[i], expectedList[i]))
                Assert.Fail("Property {0}.{1} does not match. Expected IList with element {1} equals to {2} but was IList with element {1} equals to {3}", property.PropertyType.Name, property.Name, expectedList[i], actualList[i]);
    }
}
```

I took this from here: [Compare equality between two objects in NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318210/compare-equality-between-two-objects-in-nunit) (Juanmas' answer)

Say I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IView
{
    decimal ID { get; set; }
    decimal Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then have two views like this:

```
IView view = new FormMain();
IView view2 = new FormMain();
```

view and view2 are then given properties.

I then want to compare the interfaces so I do this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(Helper.PropertyValuesAreEquals(view, view2), true);
```

However, this produces an exception:

> "Property Get method was not found.".

How can I ensure this function only gets properties for the properties in my interface?

Should I even be unit testing a view like this?

Comment: You could consider using Generics, also in the logic above you should check if property exists in both objects provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Property Get method was not found.` error occurs when you have property with only setter, e.g. `int MyProperty { set { x = value; } }`.

So you need to just skip these properties in your `PropertyValuesAreEquals` method.

If you want to check only properties that belongs to specific interface, you must change your method to something like this:

```
public static void PropertyValuesAreEquals<T> (T actual, T expected)
{
     PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof (T).GetProperties ();
     //...
}
```

Now we can run this method: `PropertyValuesAreEquals<IView> (view, view2);`

Don't forget about `<IView>` parameter; otherwise compiler may use `FormMain` type as a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Generics, also in the logic above you should check if property exists in both objects provided and can be read.

```
public static void PropertyValuesAreEquals<T>(T actual, T expected) 
    where T : class {
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);
    foreach (var property in properties) {
        var expectedValue = property.GetValue(expected, null);
        var actualValue = property.GetValue(actual, null);

        if (actualValue is IList)
            AssertListsAreEquals(property, (IList)actualValue, (IList)expectedValue);
        else if (!Equals(expectedValue, actualValue))
            Assert.Fail("Property {0}.{1} does not match. Expected: {2} but was: {3}", property.DeclaringType.Name, property.Name, expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
}
```

And used in your case as

```
Assert.IsTrue(Helper.PropertyValuesAreEquals<IView>(view, view2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a generic function without specifying of type for "actual" and "expected".

```
public static void PropertyValuesAreEquals<T>(object actual, object expected)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(actual is T);
    Assert.IsTrue(expected is T);

    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(o => o.CanRead))
    {
        var actualValue = property.GetValue(actual, null);
        var expectedValue = property.GetValue(expected, null);

        ...
    }
}
```