# NUnit Assert.AreEqual(LeftObject,RigtObject)

Tags: c#, nunit

The following links suggest that this should work.

1. [Compare equality between two objects in NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318210/compare-equality-between-two-objects-in-nunit)
2. [NNunt Documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.AreEqual.html)

   ```
   [TestFixture()]
   public class ResponseMessageUnitTests
   {

       private Mock<IConfiguration> _IConfigurationMoq;
       private Mock<ICardReader> _ICardReaderMoq;
       private ResponseMessage responseMessage; 

       public ResponseMessageUnitTests()
       {
           //Act
           this._IConfigurationMoq = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
           _IConfigurationMoq.Setup(x => x.REPEATDELAYTIME).Returns(0);
           _IConfigurationMoq.Setup(x => x.COLOUR_WHOLE_RESPONSE_AREA).Returns(true);
           this._ICardReaderMoq = new Mock<ICardReader>();
           this.responseMessage = new ResponseMessage(_IConfigurationMoq.Object, _ICardReaderMoq.Object);
       } 

       [Test(Description =
       "Calling ResponseMessage DisplayAdditionalInfo_Empty Method " +
       "with a Background Colour that populates the fields " +
       "AdditionalInfoLine[1-4] and " +
       "AdditionalInfoNo[1-4]")]
       [TestCase(BACKGROUNDCOLOURS.GOOD)]
       public void ResponseMessage_DisplayAdditionalInfo_Empty(string backgroundColour)

       {
           //Arrange
           _IConfigurationMoq.Setup(x => x.COLOUR_WHOLE_RESPONSE_AREA).Returns(true);
           _IConfigurationMoq.Setup(x => x.REPEATDELAYTIME).Returns(0);

           DisplayLine expected = new DisplayLine(_IConfigurationMoq.Object, null, null, backgroundColour);

           //Act
           responseMessage.DisplayAdditionalInfo_Empty(backgroundColour);

           //Assert
           Assert.AreEqual(expected,responseMessage.AdditionalInfoLine1);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoLine2);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoLine3);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoLine4);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoNo1);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoNo2);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoNo3);
           //Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseMessage.AdditionalInfoNo4);
       }
   ```

If I place a breakpoint on the line with the Assert.AreEqual, I get the following:

[image: The objects being compared]

The tests **fails** to my surprise with the following error message:

```
Message:   Expected: <EPIC.APIS.REST.Models.Android.DisplayLine>
           But was:  <EPIC.APIS.REST.Models.Android.DisplayLine>
```

I don't understand why... The 2 objects are of the same type and contain the same values?

```
 <package id="NUnit" version="3.12.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Comment: Does your `DisplayLine` class override `Equals`?

Comment: No, it does not have an Equals override.

Comment: Your link to https://docs.nunit.org/2.2.2/comparisonAsserts.html is legacy documentation... It even says so at the top of the page! I edited your question so that the link goes to the current documentation. Please try to avoid confusing yourself and others with obsolete docs - NUnit 2.2.2 is from 2004!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as the threads you linked to suggest, `Assert.AreEqual` compares as a reference equal unless you override it.

So even though everything looks the same, they're probably different object / references.

You could have a look at the `PropertyValuesAreEquals` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/318238/919324 and either compare your objects like that, or override the comparison of the objects

Comment: To get an intelligent error message, you should also override ToString() on the object. If you don't do that, only the class name is shown for user-defined Types.

Comment: Great suggestion. What I did was create an Equals method for my DisplayLine class.
I could then call this Equals method in my test. Assert.IsTrue(expected.Equals(responseMessage.AdditionalInfoLine1));